# Cannot factory reset a MacBook running OSX 10.5 using Disk Utility

Tags: macbook-pro

I just bought a used 2007 MacBook running Mac OS X 10.5, 2GHZ Intel Core 2 Duo. I want to return it to factory spec to erase all previous owner's information and start fresh.

Disk Utility's Erase buttons is greyed out.

How can I do this? I have no startup disc.

Comment: Do you have access to any other Macs? If so, can you specify which models?

Answer (score 2):

There is no recovery partition on that one so no "Internet Recovery." you will need to make an installation DVD or USB key.

Log onto the app store and see if you have the option to download MacOS Lion (the latest version compatible with that Mac).

Failing that and a friend with the ability to download a compatible OS install for you, you might want to see if an Apple Genius can help you get that OS downloaded.

Failing that, it's time to hit Craigslist or eBay

Comment: The App Store wasn't added until 10.6.6, so that won't be an option. Apple [claims to still have 10.6 discs available](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) for $19.99. I think that's 10.6.3, but the 10.6.8 is a free update [available online](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399). I don't think the free upgrade from 10.6 to 10.7 is available anymore, but the Apple store [lists 10.7 available as a "content code"](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/D6106Z/A/os-x-lion) (also $19.99), but I'm not sure what that actually gets you.

Comment: Does OP live near an Apple Store? Instead of buying a disk, if OP takes the computer into an Apple Store they’ll do the OS install for free.

Comment: OOPS! accidentally down voted. Sorry, Steve, I had no inkling to do so. Anyone know how to undo this?

Comment: I think you can just up vote your downvote to cancel it out

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the DVD that came with it, or order a new one if you don't have it.

An alternative would be upgrading to 10.6, which might be faster or easier. You can order it online but some stores might still have it. https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard